# What does Sam shout when he uses the Phial?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

In the Two Towers, near the beginning of chapter "The Choices of Master Samwise", Sam uses the Phial and shouts in (I assume) elvish:

> A Elbereth Gilthoniel
>
> o menel palan-diriel,
>
> le nallon sí di'nguruthos!
>
> A tiro nin, Fanuilos!

What language is this exactly, and what does he say?

Comment: Related: [What does Frodo say when he pulls out the phial?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158681/85712)

Comment: I was also thinking of asking _why_ Sam spoke Sindarin and not, say, Quenya, and I suppose how and why the words came to him at all. I guess that should be a separate question?

Comment: @jknappen but [please don't crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Sam was speaking Sindarin and crying a prayer to Elbereth

The translations are sourced from [here](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/elbereth.htm), as well as there relevant source books. The direct translation seems to come from the Letters, specifically the infamous *211 To Rhona Beare*, and the poetic translation seems to be from Tolkien himself, for the book *The Road Goes Ever On* by Donald Swann

> O Elbereth Starkindler
> from heaven gazing afar,
> to thee I cry now in the shadow of (the fear of) death!
> O look towards me, Everwhite!
> <sub>[The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien - Letter 211, To Rhona Beare](https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/the_letters_of_j.rrtolkien.pdf)</sub>

> O! Queen who kindled star on star, white-robed from heaven gazing far, here overwhelmed in dread of Death I cry: O guard me, Elbereth!
> <sub>The Road Goes Ever On, "A Elbereth Gilthoniel"</sub>

Sam's invocation is highly related to the prayer to Elbereth (Varda) titled "[*A Elbereth Gilthoniel*](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/A_Elbereth_Gilthoniel)"

Comment: Not surprising that we both ended up at the same resource... :)

Comment: Ah, so this is the origin of Elbereth in Nethack...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is _211 To Rhona Beare_ infamous?

Comment: @Elia if you have any questions about Tolkien’s legendarium, chances are it’s answered in Letter 211

Comment: @Elia: I was curious myself, so I did a bit of DuckDuckGo'ing -- *Letter 211, To Rhona Beare* was apparently [six pages long and covered some of the most extreme nitpicks I've ever heard of in a fan letter](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_211).

Comment: @tonysdg that letter along with 131 (If I'm remembering the numbers correctly) have at least half the answers to the questions I've seen people ask that aren't directly asked in LotR or the Hobbit.

Answer (score 14):

The [Ardalambion](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/) indicates that it’s Sindarin, and provides a [translation of this](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/elbereth.htm):

> **A Elbereth Gilthoniel o menel palan-diriel, le nallon**
>   *O Elbereth Starkindler from firmanent gazing afar, to thee I cry*
>   **sí di-nguruthos! A tiro nin, Fanuilos!**
>   *here beneath death-horror! O look towards me, Everwhite!*

It continues with JRRT’s own translation(s) of this, given as

> "O! Queen who kindled star on star, white-robed from heaven gazing far, here overwhelmed in dread of Death I cry: O guard me, Elbereth!"

or

> "O Elbereth Starkindler from heaven gazing-afar, to thee I cry now in the shadow of (the fear of) death. O look towards me, Everwhite."