# How and why does Sam know to say that Sindarin phrase when he uses the Phial?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

Following on from my question [What does Sam shout when he uses the Phial?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186464/85712), I was curious to know why those words came to him, and why they were in Sindarin specifically.

It would be more plausible for Frodo to know that phrase since Frodo knows some elvish (Quenya, at least, I can't remember if anywhere says how many dialects of elvish he knows) but Sam, to the best of my knowledge, doesn't know any elvish, which implies that the words were put in his head... somehow. If so, how, and by who? (At this point I'm just following tangents of speculation, so I'll stop here...)

So, **how and why does he know to say those words?**

Comment: Because he read the author's notes, obviously.

Comment: I think there's an answer besides amflare's, but I need to look  in _The Fellowship of the Ring_ to see what Gildor is actually singing at Woody End.

Comment: @Spencer. Gildor's company are singing of Elbereth when the hobbits meet them at Woody End, but the words are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember how Galdriel corrects Sam when he speaks of elvish magic. I don't think that either Tolkien or the elves would think of Sam's words as "magic", as in *say these words and this will happen*.

Sam is saying a prayer to Elbereth (Varda) one of the two most powerful guardians living on Arda (the world). The words are in [What does Sam shout when he uses the Phial?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186464/what-does-sam-shout-when-he-uses-the-phial) (which is linked to this question), and the translation is given in Edlothian's answer to that question. As a Christian, Tolkien believes that prayers are powerful, but the power comes, not from the actual words, but from the intention and the faith behind them.

**How does Sam know the words?** They are similar to, but not the same as, the words he heard when he met Gildor in the Shire. It is possible that he heard this version of the prayer while staying at Rivendell. We are told that he is thinking of the elves of Rivendell singing to Elbereth immediately before he utters the prayer.

> ‘Galadriel!’ he said faintly, and then he heard voices far off but clear: the crying of the Elves as they walked under the stars in the beloved shadows of the Shire, and the music of the Elves as it came through his sleep in the Hall of Fire in the house of Elrond.
>
> Gilthoniel A Elbereth!
>
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* Book Four, Chapter 10: *The Choices of Master Samwise*</sub>
>
> <sub>Page 729 (Houghton Mifflin Harcourt; Single Volume 50th Anniversary Edition)</sub>

**What prompts Sam to say those words?** I think we have to assume that his use of the words (and perhaps the words themselves) are inspired. So who inspired them? Tolkien often makes clear that something is **meant** to happen without explicitly saying **who** means it to happen. We may often feel that it must be Eru or one of the Valar, and I think we can do the same here. Not so much a case of *Deus ex machina* but more of *Deus ex Deo*.

Answer (score 12):

There appears to be some sort of magic involved, though this is never explicitly addressed in the books.

> Even as Sam himself crouched, looking at [Shelob], seeing his death in her eyes, **a thought came to him, as if some remote voice had spoken,** and he fumbled in his breast with his left hand, and found what he sought: cold and hard and solid it seemed to his touch in a phantom world of horror, the Phial of Galadriel.
>
> 'Galadriel! ' he said faintly, and then he heard voices far off but clear: the crying of the Elves as they walked under the stars in the beloved shadows of the Shire, and the music of the Elves as it came through his sleep in the Hall of Fire in the house of Elrond.
>
> *Gilthoniel A Elbereth!*
>
> **And then his tongue was loosed and his voice cried in a language which he did not know:**
>
> *A Elbereth Gilthoniel
>
>   o menel palan-diriel,
>
>   le nallon sí di’nguruthos!
>   A tiro nin, Fanuilos!*
>
> **And with that he staggered to his feet and was Sam wise the hobbit, Hamfast's son, again.**
>   <sub>*The Two Towers - Chapter 10: The Choices of Master Samwise*</sub>

<sup>(bolded emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: He's speaking in tongues, essentially.

Comment: I always thought of that scene as a Deus Ex Machina to be honest.

Comment: @Loki You mean the part about him knowing what the magic phrase was, or the part with the magic vial? :)

Comment: @Loki One of the plot points of the whole trilogy is that there is some larger force guiding the destruction of the Ring. So yes, there was literally a god in a machine in LoTR, if you consider the machine to be the plot.

Comment: @JonKiparsky I meant the part of him knowing the magic phrase all of a sudden via a "distant voice" aka Tolkien :D

Comment: @ToddWilcox I completely agree, but the "god" in that case was Tolkien himself.

Comment: @Loki My interpretation of Gandalf's interpretation is that the god in question is actually Eru/Illuvatar. At one point Gandalf says something along the lines of, "All I know is somehow Bilbo was *meant* to find the ring. There's some larger force at work here". That's the gist of it anyway. Although i remember the word "meant" in italics.

Comment: The quote also suggests that Sam could have heard the song (without knowing the meaning of the words) while staying at Rivendell.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox Finally, someone who understands the reason for sending two Hobbits on a hopeless suicide mission that has no chance of success!